# Avoid Beep sound when enter keypress in a textbox

Tags: asp.net, javascript, onkeypress

When you create an aspx page as this one:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

how can you avoid the beep sound that happens when you are in a textbox and hit enter.

On the other hand I would like to handle the enter onkeypress event.

Tx!

Comment: What browser, OS are you using?

Comment: Internet Explorer 7.0/8.0Beta and Windows Vista SP1 But it is more related to the browser.

Comment: This would be a web solution, so I won't be able to disable it for every user. Is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's related to the browser that your audience is using, then they're used to it happening, because it happens on every other site besides yours. I'd say it's not worth worrying about - kind of like people with JavaScript turned off. They know they've got it turned off, and they're accustomed to sites lacking certain functionality as a result. You can't force them to turn it on, and you can't force them to turn the sound thing off. It's one of those experience comprises you've got to accept in web apps.

Comment: nor what I expected, as I would like to get the same experience for all my users

Comment: It doesn't happen on every site. It is a direct result of how the page is codes as explained in other responses.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, it is NOT standard behavior to get a beep when pressing enter in a textbox on a webpage.  Try Google's search page, or for that matter try the Name, Email, and Home Page fields at the bottom of this page.  None of them beep when pressing enter - in any browser.

To prevent the beep, handle the onKeyDown event on your `<INPUT>` tag and return false if the enter key is pressed:

```
<input type="text" name="TextBox1" value="" onKeyDown="return StopBeepOnEnter(event)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function StopBeepOnEnter(event)
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 13)
        {
            // Do Whatever...

            return false; // This stops the beep
        } 
    }
</script>
```

And here is the same thing using jQuery (I've actually tested this and it solved the problem for me):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").keydown(function(event)
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 13)
        {
            // Do Whatever...

            return false; // This stops the beep
        }
    });
</script>
```

I found the solution on this thread - credit to Tharn Jaggar:

http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=36491

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things to note here...

1. The alert will occur if the submit button is hidden or if there is no submit button at all.  This is often the case if you hand-roll your own `<a>` buttons like I usually do (because default OS buttons are ugly).  One thing you may want to look into is using `<button type="submit"></button>` because you can style them a lot more than standard input buttons and they will handle the key events organically.
2. The alert will still occur if you intercept keyCode 13 on `keyup` or `keydown`.  I don't know what it is about these events, but you have to use `keypress`.  This is what I usually do with jQuery on a global level...

   ```
   $("input[type=text],input[type=password]").keypress(function(e) {    
     if(e.keyCode == 13) {
       $(this).closest("form").trigger("submit");
       e.preventDefault();
     }
   });
   ```

   And then on the page level I trap the submit event and do my validation routines...

   ```
   $("form").submit(function(e) {
     var txt = $("#txtUser");
     if(txt.val().length == 0) {
       alert("Who are you?");
       txt.focus();
       e.preventDefault();
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: It seems to occur if there is more than one text box and no submit button. And the solution that worked for me is to return false from the keypress event specifically.

Comment: The other interesting thing is that it doesn't seem to happen if the form only has one textbox. I suspect this is a vestige of the ISINDEX function in early version of HTML which handled a single textbox in a specific manner...haven't thought of that in a long time!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your form tag `onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13)return false;"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn it off in your sound preferences on your operating system. It's an Internet Explorer thing.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much of anything in asp, but my first thought is that it would be similar to a Winforms application. My first step in solving it would be to set the key (code, keycode, whatever it's named in the event) var to #0 or null, as well as any vars such as e.handled in the event call prior to returning.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to disable the beep sound on all the components of the page while pressing Enter key in textfield or combo or any component, which was required. What I did is I added [onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13)return false;"] in my body tag like given below:

```
   <body onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13)return false;">
```

I used above code in my GWT GXT Application.

Krishan Babbar

Answer (score 0):

`KeyPressEvent.preventDefault()`  seems to do the trick in GWT